# Buttons are buggy in IE 8

Tags: support, user-interface, browser-support

This is screenshot of a UI issue - overlaid buttons:

[image]

I am on browser:

[image]

I happen to have no choice about browser (gov PC)

Comment: Does [so] support IE 8? _Should_ it?

Comment: Nope. IE8 [has not been supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) for a while now.

Comment: As an aside, there probably should be laws to prevent governments from inflicting IE8 to the people working for them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  - Well, they just  can do statistics on users. If enough % use IE then ... sure it'd be nice to support !

Comment: 2015 - 2009 = ?

Comment: @Coffee Sorry, IE is crap. IE 8 in particular, even Microsoft recommends you to update to the latest version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Admittedly, it's pretty bad. *sigh*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've saw an NHS hospital over here running IE 6 last year. There really is no hope for some.

Comment: So you're a programmer at a government facility and you are forced to work with IE8 to do your job? I can understand forcing IE8 to make internal sites work properly, but this...

Comment: @Joe - was the morgue the largest department?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to fix it, at least when using devtools:

```css
#hmenus {
   text-align: center; /* or `right` */
}
```

And it shouldn't break anything on compliant browsers.